# Need to add both image and text in one article in django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 different classes for the post and the image,but I need both in one class so I can add the image related to the post from the admin site while adding post.And, I need to display the image next to the title

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: Is there any relationship like `M2M` or `O2M` between `Post` and `Image`?

Comment: yes o2o .I needed the image to be a small thumbnail and be displayed next to the post title

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OneToOne`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) relationship

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d') 


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    post_image = models.OneToOneField(Image)



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I am getting the following the error      Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such column: blog_post.post_image_id

Comment: Will you please past full traceback?

Comment: You have to create one primary_key in `Image` model. Relationship will be depend on primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the database? you should have a `post_image_id` in your `blog_post` table. (related to you no such column error). Please be aware if you are running Django 1.6 or lower `./manage.py syncdb` will not update your database table. You should use South ore update your database manually.

If you fixed the no column error you can add an image to a post. (See Lafada's example)

If you want to have a m2m relation and add multiple images to your Post.

```
image_a = Image()
image_b = Image()
blog = Blog().save() # You must save a blog before adding images in a m2m relation.
blog.images.add(image_a)
blog.images.add(image_b)
```

or

```
blog = Blog().save()

for image in images:
  blog.images.add(image)

blog.save()
```